# How to force a video to play in fullscreen in youtube player?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app where the help section has a tutorial video I want to force this video to open in Fullscreen using the Youtube player (Just like the Market/Play app does). it forces videos to play in Fullscreen even if it's a portrait video.

I use this code to force the video to open in youtube player

```
String videoId = "VIDEO_ID_HERE";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+videoId)); 
intent.putExtra("VIDEO_ID", videoId); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Rather than relying on the YouTube app to be installed, have a look at the recently launched [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). Although it'll require a bit more work to integrate, you get way more control on the look and feel. It includes a bunch of examples, of which the [**Custom Fullscreen Handling**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Custom_Fullscreen_Handling) should be of particular interest to you.

Comment: I believe there's a way to do it without that API, the market app does it already, it opens in the installed Youtube player already, I think there would be something like intent.putExtra("KEYWORD_HERE", true);

Comment: Is the source code for Google Play available? I would search for the video part in it if it is.

Comment: I think you're right, based on the documentation for the [`YouTubeIntents#canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions(Context)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions%28android.content.Context%29) method. Looks like support for a `fullscreen` parameter depends on the YouTube app version installed. Have a look around for that parameter, or alternatively, see if you can check out the source for that method somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, one more comment. There's also a [`createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(...)`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) util method that you could use (or base your own implementation on). Not sure why I didn't spot that one before...

Comment: But still that's  in the Youtube API right?

Comment: I have found this Piece of code But I don't know how to send the Player Parameters Should it be a HashMap or what ?  http://pastebin.com/7DknN1kZ

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Youtube v4.1.47 app cando it for you

```
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
```

I dont know about lower versions.

Comment: It wasn't support in the older versions, as the play store doesn't do that in old versions

Comment: Do you know where I can find the documentation of this?