# “href” value in HTML to open video in youtube app or market (Google Play) on Android

Tags: android, html, android-intent, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm making a Web Page that shows 360 videos, but i recently noticed that 360 functionality in the android browser is not supported, and because of this the video wont shows correctly, so after searching a lot i found that the best option is to try to open the video in the YouTube app making use of an "Android Intent" explained in this developer tutorial:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

So i need to construct the href address for a YouTube video, but unfortunately i don't know android programming and also can't find the YouTube App xml manifest to fill the options, can anyone help me?

```
intent:
   HOST/URI-path <-- I think here needs to be the video URL? 
   #Intent; 
      package=com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeIntents; <-- Is this the correct package? or should i use com.google.android.youtube.player? 
      action=createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(context, UUweNrpFTwA, true, true); <-- Dont know what to put in context field 
      category=[string]; <-- Is category needed? if so what category should i place here?
      component=[string]; <-- Is component needed?
      scheme=youtube; <-- Is this the correct scheme?
   end;
```

Any help or tutorial will be greatly appreciated... Thanks!!

Comment: You didn't say the language that you want to use.

Comment: I'm trying to open YouTube from a webpage using html tags, theoretically is possible according to this tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## 1) Intent solution :

```
<a href="
intent:
  //8xn9iq3lG_w/
  #Intent;
    scheme=vnd.youtube;
    package=com.google.android.youtube
    S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube;
end;
">youtube or market</a>
```

**NB:**

Maybe you need to remove spaces in *href attribut*:

```
<a href="intent://8xn9iq3lG_w/#Intent;scheme=vnd.youtube;package=com.google.android.youtube;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.google.android.youtube;end;">youtube or market</a>
```

[image: video]

---

## 2) Link solution :

You get more information in **Settings** > **Apps** > **Youtube** > **Open by default** > **Supported links**:

- youtube.be
- m.youtube.com
- youtube.com
- www.youtube.com

See: https://youtu.be/8xn9iq3lG_w and try, here: http://output.jsbin.com/tubozokebe/

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://youtu.be/8xn9iq3lG_w">link: https://youtu.be/8xn9iq3lG_w</a> or
<a target="_blank" href="vnd.youtube:8xn9iq3lG_w">link: vnd.youtube:8xn9iq3lG_w</a>
```

[image: video]

Comment: Yes, but this solution wont redirect the user to the playstore if youtube app is not installed, and <a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a> will do... thats why i need to change this example and fill the correct information for the youtube app

Comment: Do you know if is it possible to automatically play the video on full screen?

Comment: I don't know, I [try to add extra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064244/how-to-force-a-video-to-play-in-fullscreen-in-youtube-player) but I don't know how to do with html.

Comment: Where is the official documentation of href="intent:// ?

Comment: @VincentAlex https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
      window.location="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=youtube;package=com.google.youtube;end"

I am not sure about it...But try.