# “href” value in HTML to open URL in Chrome App

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I want to open a url in Chrome App via just clicking at href Link.

`<a href="googlechrome://http://www.google.co.in">Google Chrome</a>`

I have tried this but I can't understand , why its just opening Google chrome App..., I need to open a URL with Chrome app.

Is there is any code like:

`<a target="_blank" href="vnd.youtube:8xn9iq3lG_w">Youtube Video</a>`

This link opening a video in Youtube App via just clicking at LINK.

Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this...

Comment: This answer may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024729/href-value-in-html-to-open-video-in-youtube-app-or-market-google-play-on-and

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Apps signal the browser that they can take care of specific URLs, for the example the youtube app picks "www.youtube.com", and then the browser you use will ask you if you want to open that with the youtube app. At least that's my understanding of this.

Comment: The way I understand it working from the link to the answer I commented, is that an app can be built to signal its' intent to open all urls meeting a criteria, even if the url itself does not signal the same intent.
However, the href of an anchor tag can also signal a similar intent, indicating what app should open it if present.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Intent for doing this. I am posting an example for it -

```
<a href="intent://stackoverflow.com#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end"> Open in Chrome </a>
```

This way, if this link is called from some other browser in Android, it will open stackoverflow.com in Chrome.

Comment: This not working in in-app browser, any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<a href="intent://google.co.in#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end">Clicking this link should open it in the Chrome app. But if Chrome is not installed/activated, the device's intent chooser should offer the means to download it from Google Play, APK Pure, etc...</a>`

[More info here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/intents).