# How to Play YouTubePlayList Intent videos in Full Screen

Tags: android

I am beginner in android and I am developing an app in which I am using YouTube Data API in order to show YouTube videos of specific Playlist. I am succeed in doing so but there is a problem that whenever the user clicks on any video from that playlist, That video plays as default the YouTube video plays in YouTube app . I want that whenever user clicks any video it should play in Device YouTube App with Full Screen 
Every Kind of help is appreciated!
Here is my main activity code:

```
    package com.example.pc.fkidshell;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeIntents;

public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar third_toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        third_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_thirdtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(third_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.sectitle);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.tblogo);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    public void OnClickButtonListener()
    {
        Button youtubebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        youtubebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String PLAYLIST_ID = "PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40";
                Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayPlaylistIntent(Main4Activity.this, PLAYLIST_ID);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the extra of `force_fullscreen` as `true`

```
intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
```

Referring you to another answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064588/4434834

Comment: This only works with YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent() not with YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(Main4Activity.this, PLAYLIST_ID)